# R-2R for HQ sound output

Tags: dac

I am building MP3 player. Some time ago I was asking about feasibility of building headphones driver based on D-class amplifier. Now I am tired, I want to go for simple R-2R network, followed by opamp.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I need to get 44100@16 bit stereo sound.

As I don't have crystals which are multiple of 44100 (the only frequency I need to support), I oversample sound to let's say 125kHz (from 25Mhz crystal). Then I output data from uC to 595 serial counters, and latch it in hardware to avoid any jitter due to interrupts and stuff (but if I would set it as highest priority interrupt, it might work just fine even when driven directly from uC).

Just before latch I turn 595/uC outputs into Z-state to avoid spikes during transition.

Then R2R(0.1%), then opamp, then headphones. As I might get some non-linearity, I can calibrate each output code individually on 24-bit precision ADC with precision reference voltage source I have, and store calibration values into flash.

Will it work and produce decent sound quality, or are there any pitfalls? I know that it's easier to get audio DAC, but seems like there are not much available, and what is available costs ~20$, and I am not a big fan of waiting 2-3-4 weeks for a part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Will it work and produce decent sound quality, or are there any pitfalls?*

Building a 16 bit DAC out of two '595 chips, a R-2R ladder, and a headphone op-amp such as the LM386N-3 should easily give you 8 bit precision; perhaps with some effort 12 bit precision (ENOB), which is better than telephone quality.
Perhaps that will be adequate for testing/debugging the rest of your design while you wait for a single-chip DAC to come in the mail.

The Delta-Sigma DAC ("1-bit DAC") is also clever and has much less resistor-matching problems than R-2R. If you go that route you might look at the slightly more clever [Roman Black BTc Sound Compression Algorithm](http://www.romanblack.com/btc_alg.htm).
My understanding is that both delta-sigma and BTc can be converted into a high-efficiency form equivalent to a class-D amplifier by replacing the resistors in the output RC filter with inductors, resulting in a LC filter.

I generally encourage people to build things themselves at least once in order to more fully understand them, rather than always buying a black box.
But in this particular case I agree with David Kessner and Olin Lathrop:
If you really want more than 12 bit resolution, you'll probably spend far less time and energy if you buy one of the low-cost single-chip ADCs available.
I guess I'm spoiled living in a country where I can easily obtain any of the chips mentioned in
[Picking a DAC for an audio amplfier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17001/picking-a-dac-for-an-audio-amplfier)
in less than a week.

If you are having trouble getting one particular part from one particular manufacturer, perhaps you could look at some other low-cost "precision audio" DAC from some other manufacturer:

- Wolfson Microelectronics, such as the WM8726
- Texas Instruments, such as the PCM1780
- Maxim, such as the MAX5556
- Analog Devices, such as the AD5662
- Linear Technology, such as the LTC2602
- NXP Semiconductor, such as the UDA1334
- AKM Semiconductor, such as the AK4386
- Silicon Laboratories, such as the SI3000
- Cirrus Logic, such as the CS4334

While you're waiting for the single-chip DAC to come in the mail, perhaps you could plunge ahead with the rest of your design.
If you're really doing MP3 decoding in real time, I suspect you are going to have many other difficult parts to your project; perhaps it will be useful to have two '595 chips holding the decoded data to help you debug the software,  and perhaps even afterward.
Get something simple making a few beeps first, then later tweak it to give better sound quality.

Have you seen the [list of open-source music players](http://opencircuits.com/Music_Player)?

Comment: MP3 decoding is already working - not a big deal with modern ARMs. Thanks for awesome list of DAC's, I'll check them out. I've seen many open projects, but I have some unique requirements, like RF remote control )

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider the accuracy of the resistors required to implement a R-2R ladder.  Even .1% as you mention is only 1 part in 1000, or good for about 10 bits.  If you implement a wider ladder with these resistors, the additional codes will be scattered around and not monotonic.

It is a lot easier to match and trim resistors on a single chip, which is how they can achieve 16 bits at reasonable cost.  I haven't looked, but it surprises me that audio frequency 16 bit DACs cost $20.  My knee jerk reaction is that's too high.  It also doesn't make sense that getting such a part takes 2-4 weeks.

I saw a technique once that used a bunch more bits in a R-2R ladder than the resistor tolerance could support.  In fact it wasn't exactly 2x between the resistors so that the resulting voltages would be more evenly scattered.  This guy then measured the result of every last code accurately, and found the subset that gave the desired response for the number of bits he actually wanted.  The output value then went thru a lookup table before driving the R-2R ladder.  Of course if temperature drifts a bit, the mapping is no longer valid.

Comment: Well, if resistors are of same type, they should have pretty much the same temperature coefficient...

Comment: @BarsMonter: Yes, and they will "pretty much" work then as the temperature changes.  At 16 bits you need one part in 66000, or 15ppm matching.  Separate discrete resistors can easily be mismatched to more than 15ppm/degC, so even a single degC temperature change would invalidate the calibration.  You can get multiple resistors on a chip matched to 5ppm/degC and better, but at that point you might as well get a real D/A that has already been trimmed and is specified to work over your temperature range.

Answer (score 2):

Olin said some good stuff.  I'd like to add a couple of things:

There are many audio DAC's that are less than US$3 each.  I just did a search on Digikey for CS43 (Cirrus Logic DACs start with that) and found 46 stereo DAC's.  The most expensive was US$7.80, but 90% of them were less than US$5.  Even the cheapest of these will have better performance than a hand-made R-2R ladder.

While you're at Digikey, they offer dozens of oscillators at 11.2896 MHz or 22.579 MHz (which are 256 or 512 times 44.1 KHz).  Many of these are less than US$2.

One "trick" to using normal audio DAC's is that you need a decent sample clock (also called the LRCLK), and serial bit clock (SCLK).  These cannot normally be bit-banged by the CPU.  But in your R-2R scheme you couldn't do it off an interrupt anyway.  Even if it was on the highest priority interrupt you would still have some jitter on the order of 40+ ns.  With audio, you'd prefer the jitter to be 2 ns or less.

Your idea of using a precision ADC to calibrate each R-2R output code could work, but you would need a table of 2^16 bits, or 2^24 bits (depending on the number of bits).  And you'd need two tables, one for each audio channel.  This is just barely manageable for a 16 bit DAC, and almost impossible for a 24 bit DAC.

If you *really* want to make a DAC, building a first-order delta-sigma DAC in an FPGA or CPLD is super easy, and would sound a lot better than a typical home-made R-2R DAC.  But it still wouldn't sound as good as a super cheap US$2 Cirrus Logic, Burr-Brown, or AKM DAC.  Even so, I've built these types of DAC's and would be happy to provide VHDL source code.

**Update:  Added more stuff!**

Here is the VHDL code for a first-order Delta-Sigma DAC:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- First Order Delta Sigma DAC
--
-- din is a signed integer where -full_scale represents a DAC output of 0 volts
-- and +full_scale is a DAC output of VCC.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity dac_ds is
    generic (n_bits     :integer);
    port (reset         :in std_logic;
          clk           :in std_logic;
          din           :in std_logic_vector (n_bits-1 downto 0); -- Signed integer
          dout          :out std_logic
         );
end dac_ds;


architecture arch_dac_ds of dac_ds is
  signal err            :std_logic_vector (n_bits+1 downto 0) := (others=>'0'); -- Error accumulator is 2 bits larger
  signal dout_int       :std_logic := '0';
begin
  process (reset, clk)
    variable val        :std_logic_vector (n_bits+1 downto 0);
    variable fs_neg     :std_logic_vector (n_bits+1 downto 0);
    variable fs_pos     :std_logic_vector (n_bits+1 downto 0);
  begin
    if reset='1' then
      err <= (others=>'0');
      dout_int <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      val := (din(din'high) & din(din'high) & din) + err;

      fs_neg := (others=>'0');
      fs_neg(0) := '1';
      fs_neg(fs_neg'high downto fs_neg'high-2) := "111";

      fs_pos := (others=>'0');
      fs_pos(fs_pos'high-2) := '1';

      if val(val'high) = '0' then
        dout_int <= '1';
        err <= val + fs_neg;   -- err <= value + (-full scale)
      else
        dout_int <= '0';
        err <= val + fs_pos;   -- err <= value + (+full scale)
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  dout <= dout_int;

end arch_dac_ds;
```

The output will look like a pseudo-random bit stream.  I recommend running it at the highest clock frequency you can that is a power-of-2-multiple of the sample rate.  22.579 MHz would be the slowest I'd run it at.  45.xxx or 90.xxx MHz would be even better.

Normally you would run this output into a simple RC filter.  Make the R large enough that your FPGA/CPLD output can still swing rail-to-rail.  Make C large enough to filter properly.  I've used 3.3K and 0.1 uF and it works well.  0.01 uF might be better.  The output of the RC filter would then be buffered by an op-amp.  The faster the clock frequency, the easier this filter is to make and the higher the resulting accuracy is.

Just because someone will mention it:  You could do the same with a simple PWM output, but the RC filter would have to be much bigger and it's design more critical-- with less accuracy.   Ironically, in an FPGA this Delta-Sigma DAC is smaller than a similar PWM circuit.

Yes, you can make it into a sort of Class-D amplifier but the output switching rates are very high.    This means that your "power stage" would have to handle these speeds and you will have more switching losses (less efficiency) too.

This is a very simple delta-sigma DAC.  There are lots of ways to improve it if you want, but as it is it will have better performance than a home-made R-2R DAC.

Comment: Did search on CS43* on all Moscow storages, it's starting from 14$ or delivery in 4 weeks :-D If I would got with 595 driving R2R, I will get perfect DAC clock from crystal. About first-order delta-sigma - what frequency it should work on to get 16-bit resolution? Can it be made D-like class amplifier? (I.e. not wasting any power in linear mode)

Comment: @BarsMonster  I added some stuff about making a Delta-Sigma DAC to my answer.

Comment: If one doesn't mind doing some per-sample computation, one can greatly reduce the table size.  If one has a 20-bit DAC where each bit represents just a skosh less than twice as much voltage as the next, I would think one could get within a couple LSBs using 24-bit math on 19 compensation values--one for each bit.  Or, if one wanted to trade speed for table size, a table of 1024 compensation values for all combinations of the 10 MSB's, and a table of 1280 or so translation values for the 10 LSB's (the size of the table would depend on the amount of non-linearity)

Comment: @David, but doesn't this sigma-delta thing require 44kHz*65k clock to get 16-bit result?

Comment: @BarsMonster: Delta-sigma DACs have noise on the output which is related to frequency and signal amplitude.  Using a delta-sigma DAC to generate full full 16-bit precision at every point for any possible input waveform would require an insanely fast clock.  In practice, however, delta-sigma DACs can do a good job of rendering typical audio waveforms with much more modest clock speeds.